# Prevent Windows from launching Task Manager on reboot

Tags: windows, reboot

**The problem:**

To reproduce the issue, boot up Windows 10 and log in.  Start up Task Manager.  While you're at it, also go to the Performance Tab and click "Open Resource Monitor" at the bottom.  Now reboot.  When your log in, Task Manager and Resource Monitor will start up.

(Note I am running Windows 10 Home Version 21H1 in Spanish to help me learn the language. Some of my translations back into English might not be 100% the same. Let me know if you know of a possibility that the language setting could affect the described behavior.)

This is driving me crazy.  I have spent many hours trying to figure out a way to stop this from happening.  Someone at Microsoft probably thought they were doing us a favor.  Well, it is not a favor.  I believe we should have some level of control over what runs on the computer that we purchased.

**Things I've tried:**

You may do some Googling or Binging or DuckDuckGoing and read pages with people telling you to go to Settings, Account, Session Start Options, then scroll down to the "Restart Applications" section and turn off that setting, and perhaps a setting in the "Privacy" section right below it.  That does not do the trick.

Other sites with general information on start programs will tell you to go to the Services tab in Task Manager and disable whichever app is causing problems, but this is not in there.  This also does not work.

I have searched through the Task Scheduler for anything that might be starting these programs, and I cannot find them.

This [tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/138685-turn-off-automatically-restart-apps-after-sign-windows-10-a.html) page says to modify the registry, location `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`, set key `RestartApps` as DWORD to 0.  That doesn't work.

I have [changed the power options to disable fast startup](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10).  That doesn't work.

I have seen some sites that say something along the lines of, "Just close Task Manager and Performance Monitor before shutting down.".  I should not have to do that.

On principle, there should be a way to disable Windows from starting any program at startup or login that I do not want starting at startup or login.  It also seems like a huge security issue if I cannot find out what programs are starting on restart.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue.  What version of Windows 10 are you running.  Be specific with the build number.

Comment: Autoruns by Mark Russinovich is your friend. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, @Ramhound.  I should have put that in up front.  I have now added the Windows version (Windows 10 Home Version 21H1).

Comment: @Gantendo - Thanks, Autoruns is indeed incredible.  Since Task Manager and perfmon are Windows programs, I of course need to tell it to not hide Windows programs, so the list is huge!  Filtering on "Task" or "Tarea" (Task in Spanish) shows a \Microsoft\Windows\Task Manager\Interactive whose description is "Runs a task as the interactive user." which sounds like something else.  My fear is that the entry is only created during shutdown and removed after startup, so it wouldn't show up while running the system normally.

Comment: Just a guess, I cannot reproduce the issue: Open Start > Settings > Accounts > sign-in options. Scroll down to Privacy. Toggle off
`Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart.`

Comment: Thanks @Gantendo. However, I already had that turned off.